# Dropdown Navigation Bar overlay underneath menu

Tags: html, css

I have two issues with my coding.

1. when i set the background color for my Header ul it only change the background for first ul content
   not for all the others ul content.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A2K8.png)

2. And in Dropdown menu when i hover my dropdown lists are shown underneath my upnext menu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGmWS.png)

```css
body{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

/*############### NAVIGATION BAR ###############*/

header{
 background: #222222;
 height: 60px;
 font-family: 'Carter One', cursive;
}

header *{
 color: white;
}

header #navbar{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 display: block;
 transition: top 0.3s;
}

header .logo{
 float: left;
 height: inherit;
 margin-left: 2em;
}

header .logo-text{
 margin:12px;
 font-size: 1.4em;
}

header .logo-text span{
 color: aquamarine;
}

header ul{
 float: right;
 margin:0px;
 padding: 0px;
 height: inherit;
 list-style: none;
}

header ul li{
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}

header ul li ul{
 position: absolute;
 top: 60px;
 width: auto;
 display: none;
}

header ul li:hover ul{
 display: block;
}

header ul li ul li{
 width: 100%;  
}

header ul li ul li a{
 /*padding: 20px;*/
}

header ul li ul li a{
 background-color: grey;
}

header ul li a{
 display: block;
 padding: 17px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 font-size: 1em;
 text-decoration: none;
}

header ul li a:hover{
 background: #006669;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

header .toggle-menu{
 display: none;
}

.fa-leanpub, .fa-home, .fa-lightbulb, 
.fa-youtube, .fa-envelope, .fa-user{
 color: aquamarine;
 font-size: 1.3em;
}

/*############### RESPONSIVE NAVIGATION BAR ###############*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
 
 header ul{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #0E94A0 !important;
 }

 header ul li{
  width: 100%;
 }

}
```

```html
 <!-- FontAwesome -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
 <!-- Google Fonts -->
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Carter+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


 <header id="navbar">
  <div class="logo">
   <h1 class="logo-text"><span>NAV</span>BAR</h1>
  </div>
  <i class="fas fa-bars toggle-menu"></i> 
  <ul>
   <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-home"></i>&nbsp Home</a></li>
   <li>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-leanpub"></i>&nbsp Soft  &nbsp<i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="">Tally</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Excel</a></li>    
     <li><a href="">Word</a></li>    
     <li><a href="">Powerpoint</a></li>    
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-lightbulb"></i>&nbspTricks</a></li>
   <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>&nbsp Videos</a></li>
   <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp About-Us</a></li>
   <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-user"></i>&nbsp Contact-Us</a></li>
  </ul>
 </header>
```

Comment: her is the codepen link for my code https://codepen.io/JOHNakl/pen/KKdXrom